# ImageButton isnt working on Custom Notification - Android

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I'm trying to create a custom notification with ImageButton.
When onclicked, the ImageButton should start an activity named TaskActivity, but i'm unable to achieve this.

The followings are my codes:

**MainActivity.java**

***public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {***

```
    //button intents
    Intent cmdIntent = new Intent(
                       MainActivity.this, cmdButtonListener.class);
    PendingIntent pendingSwitchIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                                        MainActivity.this, 0, cmdIntent, 0);

    //notification mgr
    int notifyID = 001;
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(ns);

    //new notification
    int icon = R.drawable.icon3;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    @SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation" })
    Notification notify = new Notification(icon,getString(R.string.text),when);

    //remote views
    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),R.layout.custom_notification);
    contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.notification_image, R.drawable.icon4);
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_title, "APP TITLE");
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_text, "hello");
    contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_image, pendingSwitchIntent);
    notify.contentView = contentView; //set

    //notification intent
    Intent nIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, nIntent, 0);

    notify.contentIntent = contentIntent;

    mNotifyMgr.notify(notifyID,notify);
```

***}***

***public class cmdButtonListener extends BroadcastReceiver{***

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        System.out.println("Here, I am here");
        Intent newAct = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TaskActivity.class);
        startActivity(newAct);

    }
```

***}***

**Android Manifest**

```
  <receiver android:name=".MainActivity$cmdButtonListener" />
```

I dont know, where i'm wrong as i'm doing exactly as it is shown in most of the tutorials online. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found a solution...

Declare the below variable

```
private static Context mContext;
```

Add below code inside **public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {**

```
mContext = this;
```

Finally, change the below piece of code in **public class cmdButtonListener extends BroadcastReceiver{**

```
Intent newAct = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TaskActivity.class);
startActivity(newAct);
```

To

```
Intent Act = new Intent(mContext,TaskActivity.class);
mContext.startActivity(Act);
```